# Loop categories once with corresponding forums

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is only print the category ONCE and then their forums. But instead in prints the category several times and the forums...

My tables:

```
categories
id | name | disp_position

forums
id | cat_id | name | description | disp_position
```

Code:

```
$lastCatID = null;
$query = $db->query("SELECT f.id AS fid, f.cat_id, f.name AS forum_name, c.name AS cat_name FROM categories c 
                INNER JOIN forums f
                ORDER BY c.disp_position, c.id, f.disp_position");

<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>

<div class="catname">
<?php
if ($lastCatID != $row['cat_id']) {
echo '<h1>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</h1>';
$lastCatID = $row['cat_id'];
}
?>
</div>

<p><?=$row['forum_name']?></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

So I have 2 categories:

Test category (id 1) and test category 2 (id 2)

and these forums:

```
(1, 1, 'News & Announcements', 'Official announcements are posted here.', 1),
(2, 1, 'Proposals', 'Propose and help us improve.', 5),
(3, 2, 'Gameplay', 'Talk about the game here.', 3),
 (4, 2, 'Off Topic', 'Discuss all things not related to the game.', 4),
(5, 1, 'General', 'This forum is for general discussion.', 2),
(6, 1, 'Help & Support', 'Players helping players.', 6),
(7, 2, 'Bug Report', 'Found a bug? Help us squash it by reporting it here!', 7),
(8, 1, 'Trade', 'Sell your items or buy something you need.', 8);
```

Output:

```
Test category
News & Announcements
General
Test category
Gameplay
Off Topic
Test category
Proposals
Help & Support
Test category
Bug Report
Test category
Trade
News & Announcements
General
Test category 2
Gameplay
Off Topic
Test category 2
Proposals
Help & Support
Test category 2
Bug Report
Test category 2
Trade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join is missing a USING clause, or a WHERE clause. Basically you need to

`INNER JOIN forums f ON c.id = f.cat_id`